# how to get googleplay realtime purchases list using developer api like https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/XXX/orders page?

Tags: google-play-developer-api

I hope to show realtime billings of my products in my own manage panel. Can I get realtime status of all my order billings those days( unpaied, pending, canceled, not consumed, finished etc) by google developer api without pay token?(since if user not paid, there is no token for some orders)

Comment: I try find this too but probably is no way to do this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102780/how-i-get-the-list-of-all-products-purchased-in-my-app-by-google-play-developer

Comment: More explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953818/how-to-get-notified-about-one-time-product-purchases-on-google-play